# Images with gradients applied: better performance adding gradients via css or apply them directly to the src img?

Tags: html, css, image, performance, gradient

say I need a gradient over an image. 
I have several images like this. Performance-wise, is it better doing it directly on the image (photoshop or the like), like the attached one, or would it be better to use a css-gradient placed over the image?

[image]

Comment: honestly  I don't think there will be a big difference but in case both images (with and without gradient) have the same size then it's clear that the gradient inside the image will be better because you will simply have less CSS

Answer (score 0):

according to me the better way is to add overly over the Image. so if you want any change in future you just have to change the color code of an overly. it would be a easily way to do this